# How to find an element by name in other user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, commandparameter

I have a user control (`MainView`) with an other user control (`GridView`):

```
<local:MyGridView x:Name="GridView"/>
```

In my `MainView`, I have a button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}"  
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid}" 
        Content="Test"/>
```

In my `GridView`, I have a data grid that I want to send as a `CommanParameter`.
If the `GridView` code was in the `MainView` code, this syntax would work. What should I change?

I tried `{Binding ElementName=GridView.DataGrid}` - no success.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't use a view element as `CommandParameter`. The command is located in the viewmodel which must not be aware of the view, of the view-related types (like `DataGrid`), and of the view's concrete implementation.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. The internals of one control should not be accessible from another control. The former should instead expose a public property to enable access to its data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will solve this by adding the command to the code behind of the main view and then grab the Datagrid from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.

```
<local:MyGridView x:Name="**GridView**"/>

<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}"  
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=**GridView**}" 
        Content="Test"/>
```

You should change the ElementName from DataGrid To GridView.

Comment: thanks, I did it like this, and then grabbed the datagrid from MyGridView in the command method: sender is MyGridView myGridView. and then myGridView.DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ElementName` to directly reference an element that is defined in another control or namescope.

What you could do is to add a property to `MyGridView.xaml.cs` that exposes the `DataGrid` control:

```
public DataGrid DataGrid => dataGrid1;
```

You could then bind to this property of the element:

```
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}"  
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataGrid, ElementName=GridView}" 
        Content="Test"/>
```

A better approach would be use a shared `DataContext` (view model) and bind both controls to properties of this one.

Comment: @Tinsley: Of course it works if you add the property to `GridView`. Passing a control to a view model violates the MVVM pattern and what it is all about though.